# How does the eth_callBundle of flashbots works?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, flashbots

I'm just starting to get into flashbots, and I feel that the eth_callBundle method is amazing. How does this method perform transaction simulation, does flashbots maintain a copy of the ethereum mainchain itself, and then send the transaction to this copy of the network to be executed and return the result? I'd like to see at the source code for this method, but I'm not sure if flashbots has open-sourced this part of the code to github, can someone help me explain it, thanks!